# C++ no matching function call to transform when using lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

Okay, very stumped on this one. Works with Visual Studio, but not Code::Blocks (GNU compiler).

```
transform(m_teams.begin(), m_teams.end(), inserter(teamNames, teamNames.end()),
    [](stVecPair team) -> string { return team.first; });
```

`m_teams` is a map : `typedef map<string, vector<Person*> > stVecMap;`

`teamNames` is a set : `typedef set<string> StrSet;`

`stVecPair` is a pair matching `m_teams` : `typedef pair<string, vector<Person*> > stVecPair;`

Full Error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'transform(std::map<std::basic_string<char>, 
std::vector<Person*> >::const_iterator, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, 
std::vector<Person*> >::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >, 
RaceAnalyzer::teams() const::<lambda(RaceAnalyzer::stVecPair&)>)
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: Post the error message. Post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You don't need the explicit return type on this lambda.

Comment: @chris you may need it depending on which version of VS you are using.

Comment: Error added to post. And I used the return type because I've read sometimes you need it, and sometimes not.

Comment: @HerpDerpington, Really? That sucks. Usually compilers let you get away with leaving it off when you were supposed to put it on.

Comment: `std::map, std::vector >::const_iterator` - The error message seems to be broken.. Could you give us *raw* error message? (e.g. std::map<Key, Type, Comp, Allocator>, ........)

Comment: Based on what you've said and shown, I can't reproduce it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d38bc68cff48e3c1

Comment: @ikh, sorry, StackOverflow syntax messed it up.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here, read the mcve page linked above and post something that we can paste and compile.

Comment: @chris, it works in MSVS, but not with the GNU compiler. Maybe your link is another working version?

Comment: Actually, it might be something like this, where the set is `const` (because this is in a `const` member function and the set is presumably a non-mutable data member): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bde4d376a966c553. Anyway, the compiler used in my link is GCC, just like you said.

Comment: @chris, see post edit. I added my typedefs to the definition of the names.

Comment: chris' code is also working for me on Visual C++ 2013

Comment: @ikh, I know it works in MSVS. from the main post, on the very first line, "Works with Visual Studio, but not Code::Blocks (GNU compiler)."

Comment: @David ...also works on cygwin/g++ 4.8.3. Did you give the compiler `-std=c++11`?

Comment: also also works on mingw32-g++ 4.8.1

Comment: @ikh, that was it. Can you put that in a answer so I can mark as correct for future code::blocks users?

Comment: Your pair `typedef` does not match `m_teams`. The `value_type` of that map is `pair<const string, vector<Person *>>`.

Comment: @chris but I can see it works on mingw/cygwin/vc++ without `const`, I think that's not point of this question

Comment: @David um.. could you tell me what compiler (and exact version) and (*exact*) compiler option you use on your codeblocks proj? I guess there's some mistake on these.

Comment: @ikh, Default GNU Compiler that comes with Code::Blocks, so MinGW. I'm not sure how to get the version, but I would assume the latest. When I went into my project build options, and checked `Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]` it fixed the issue.

Comment: @ikh, Sure it works, but it's not the same type. This can really get you when you take a `const stVecPair &` and expect there to be no copies made. Anyway, David, the way to get the version is with a `-v` argument to the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, you've forgotten `-std=c++11` option >o<

Comment: @David Also I recommend you to make habit to always turn on this option as soon as you create a new project. (as I'm doing..) C++11 is good enough to use, and damn error message will come here if you forget to turn on.